# Integral estimate with Mean Value Theorem

Tags: definite-integrals, estimation

[For the sake of context:] I am working out a proof that uses Euler's summation formula to show that $H_N-\ln N-\frac{1}{2N}=\gamma+O(1/N^2)$ when $N\to\infty$.

At a certain point in the proof it is said that the estimate
$$
\int_0^{1/2}t\left(\frac{1}{(n-t+1/2)^2}-\frac{1}{(n+t+1/2)^2}\right)\,dt\leq \frac{2}{(n-1)^3}\int_0^{1/2}2t^2\,dt\,,\,\,\,n\geq2,
$$
is justified by the Mean Value Theorem. I am familiar with the MVT but I wasn't able to understand how it is used here so far. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Hint: think of the the part within the bracket as a function of $t$ on the range $(0,1/2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $f \colon [-\frac 12,\frac 12]\to \mathbf R$ by 
$$ f(x) = \frac 1{(n+x+\frac 12)^2} $$
Then $f$ is continuously differentiable with 
$$ f'(x) = -\frac{2}{(n+x+\frac 12)^3} $$
Hence, for each $t\in [0,\frac 12]$, there is some $\tau \in [-t,t]$ such that 
$$ f(-t) - f(t) = 2t\cdot f'(\tau) $$
Now, as $|\tau|\le \frac 12$, we have 
$$ f(-t)-f(t) = 2t f'(\tau) \le 2t \frac{2}{(n-\frac 12 - \frac 12)^3} = 2t \cdot \frac{2}{(n-1)^3}  $$
This gives your estimate.

Comment: That was fast!! Fantastic answer, thank you! =)